# In jQuery, what does 'this' refer to in an if statement

Tags: jquery

In the following jQuery, does

```
    $('.filter').click(function() {
        if ($('.this-div').hasClass('on-display')) {
            $(this).show;
        } else {
            $('.this-div').hide();
        }
```

Does the 'this' on line 3 then refer to the first .filter, or to the .this-div?

If it doesn't refer to .this-div, how could I make lines 2-6 basically read:

If one of the divs on the page with .this-div class also has a class of .on-display, then show that div (and any others that match). Otherwise, hide it.

Comment: this is not jQuery, it is JavaScript. Remember `$(this)[0] === this`

Comment: If you ever wonder what `this` is in a certain context, just `console.log(this)` from that context and check the output. Most modern browsers will give you an explicitly clear answer.

Answer (score 0):

Using the usual scoping rules of javascript, it's just the filter element you have the event listener on.

Answer (score 0):

`this` refers to the jQuery object containing the '.filter' element since `this` is not affected by the if statement (it is affected by the function context).

To make the code act as you would like, I would use jQuery's `.each()`

```
$('.filter').click(function() {
    $('.this-div').each(function(index){
        if ($(this).hasClass('on-display')) {
            $(this).show();
        } else {
            $(this).hide();
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In your example, `this` refers to `.filter` class, since assign it `click` event passing an anonymous function to it. 
Use Jquery has to have general list of elements that contain `.this-div`

```
var $divs = $( "div:has('.this-div')" );
```

[here](http://api.jquery.com/has-selector/) is about `has` function.
Then filter that elements that also contains `.on-display`:

```
var $res = $divs.filter("div:has('.on-display')");
```